# Bootstrap 3 Tabs Smooth Slideup and Slidedown transition effect?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, transition

I have been trying to get a smooth, and dependable slideUp and slideDown jQuery transition effect implemented on Bootstrap Tabs now for sometime.  Wondering if I'm doing this wrong perhaps?  I have put together an example of this on jsfiddle, here:  https://jsfiddle.net/xudjomxq/1/

But this seems to only work sometimes and does not slide up all of the time, but is sure to slide down all of the time.  How can I ensure that it slides up all of the time, before it slides down?

The jQuery I am using is:

```
$('#menuSub').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

    // If this is not defined than we are showing for the first time!
    // Add in the Bluebar Class (selected)!
    if (e.relatedTarget === undefined) {
        $("#menuSub").find(".content-sub").addClass("selected");
        $($(e.target).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
    }
    else {
        $($(e.relatedTarget).attr('href')).slideUp({ duration: 'fast', queue: true,
            done: function() {
                $($(e.target).attr('href')).slideDown('slow');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am targetting the `show.bs.tab` event.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing it in the correct event, however, perhaps I am not using `.done` or `.promise` properly here?

Can someone show me the correct way to do this with Bootstrap tabs?

Thank you!

Comment: how about [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xudjomxq/4/)?

Comment: Yeah, that looks great, thanks a million!

Comment: I wonder why this needs a `setTimeout` function though?

Comment: To start the slide down after slide up got over